# How to check a length of array in Karate framework?

Tags: karate

I have 2 different response from the REST Api as below

```
1. {"type":null,"title":"Request is invalid","status":"BAD_REQUEST","detail":"Please correct request and try again.","invalidParams":[{"name":"create.arg0.name","reason":"Name is required"}]}

2. {"type":null,"title":"Unicode char u0000 is not allowed","status":"BAD_REQUEST","detail":"Unicode char u0000 is not allowed"}
```

I wanna write a condtion where if `invalidParams` present in respose, then compare the contents of array. If not, `invalidParams` should be null/undefined.

```
 Scenario Outline: Create Asset Model with missing name and status
    Given url modelsUrl
    And request somedata
    When method POST
    Then status 400
    Then assert response.type == null
    Then match response.status == 'BAD_REQUEST'
    Then match (response.invalidParams != undefined && response.invalidParams[0].reason contains <reason>) OR (response.invalidParams == undefined)
```

But comparing against null/undefied & length also not working. How to handle this scenario in Karate? Normal Javascript is not working.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the link shared by riiich, the recommended approach is to do the following for an array length = 2

```
  * match response == '#[2]'
```

Answer (score 6):

To check if a member exists or to check an array's length you should use `assert`, not `match`.  I would also recomend breaking your last statement into multiple assertions for transparency.

here are some examples given a response with an array named 'arr':

**check array length**

```
...
And assert response.arr.length == 1
...
```

**check array is present**

```
...
And assert response.arr != null
...
```

**check array is absent**

```
...
And assert response.arr == null
...
```

reference: https://intuit.github.io/karate/#payload-assertions

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the input.
I have a situation more complicated and tried using `assert`, `eval` and neither seem to be working.

My response is looking like that and I would like to check if the array in the response is bigger than 1

```
  "data": {
    "listFormTemplates": {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": 6677,
          "name": "smth",    
          "useCase": null
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This returns TRUE: And eval responseData.items.length < 1
This returns FALSE: And assert responseData.items.length > 1

My response has 3 objects inside the items[].